# SpringBoot serialization issue using TestRestTemplate

Tags: jackson, spring-boot-test

I have a simple web controller to return an User entity.
This entity has a property `nonEditableProperty` that cannot be updated.

It's works fine on the web controller, the `nonEditableProperty` value is listed but on the `UserControllerTest` it doesn't work and the returned value is always `null`.

The annotation `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)` seems to be ignored during the test serialization.

Does anyone have any clue for this issue?
Should I load some Jackson configuration for the tests?

```
@Getter
@Entity
class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String nonEditableProperty;

    User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String nonEditableProperty) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nonEditableProperty = nonEditableProperty;
    }

}

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public Collection<User> getAllUsers() {
        return (Collection<User>) userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return userRepository.findOne(id);
    }

}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

        @Test
        public void getUserShouldReturnData() {

            ResponseEntity<User> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity("/users/{id}", User.class, 1);
            assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);

            assertThat(response.getBody().getName()).isEqualTo("Muhammed Suiçmez");
            assertThat(response.getBody().getNonEditableProperty()).isEqualTo("Non editable property");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`testRestTemplate.getForEntity(URI url, Class<T> responseType)` Fetches the api response by hitting `url` and then converts response to the type given by `responseType`

Though the API response fetched by hitting URL received the `nonEditableProperty` value ([parse inputMessage.getBody here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java#L222)), While deserializing it to `responseType` the value was lost, because of `READ_ONLY` Jackson property.